# Nested alt in plantUML Syntax

Tags: plantuml

How to add nested alt flow in plant UML ?

I have a use case in which I want nested alt. Similar to below

When I add it only innermost alt is displayed. Need help in finding right syntax for it

```
alt [condition 1]

  do some steps

   alt [condition 2]

    
    do some steps
    
  else [condition 2 Not true] so do nothing
  

else  [condition 2 Not true] so do nothing
```

Comment: Can you please add some actual code you tried for this?

Answer (score 10):

You have to add an `end` statement to close the `alt` block.

As a side note: You do not need to add the square brackets in your `alt` statements. PlantUML renders those itself.

```
alt condition 1
bob -> alice
   alt condition 2
   bob -> alice
   else condition 3
   bob -> alice
   end
else  condition 4
bob -> alice
end
```